# gtkmm - multiple windows/popup window

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I've been searching a lot and I still can't find a good example of how to have multiple windows inside the same application with `GTK`. My program is in `C++` but I don't mind an example in `C` which would help me understand the principle anyway.

So, the basic idea is to create my own derived object from `Gtk::Window` as opposed to `Gtk::Dialog`. `Dialog` has a run method which works flawlessly to open a modal popup window, but it's not flexible enough for what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know how I'd go about spawning a new window when I click a button in my program?

For example:

```
void MainWindow::on_button_clicked()
{

    NewWindow window;
    //Some code to display that window and stay in a loop until told to return
}
```

Where NewWindow is derived from `Gtk::Window` as such:

```
class NewWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

   //Normal stuff goes here

}
```

Anything will help...I'm really confused here!

Answer (score 5):

Another way to have a new window is to create a pointer to a Gtk window variable(`Gtk::Window* about_window_;`) then set the Gtk window variable to a new instance of the other window (`about_window_ = new Window;`), after that show the new window (`about_window_->show();`). Below is a full example of this:

```
class AboutWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    AboutWindow();
    ~AboutWindow();

protected:
    Gtk::Label lbl_;
};

AboutWindow::AboutWindow()
{
    this->set_default_size(100, 100);
    this->set_title("About");

    lbl_.set_label("About label");
    this->add(lbl_);

    this->show_all_children();
}

AboutWindow::~AboutWindow()
{

}

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void onButtonClicked();
    void aboutWinClose();

    Gtk::Button button_;
    Gtk::Label lbl_;
    Gtk::Box box_;
    Gtk::AboutWindow* aboutw_;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    this->set_default_size(100, 100);
    box_.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    this->add(box_);
    box_.pack_start(lbl_);

    lbl_.set_label("a test");

    button_.set_label("Open About Window");
    box_.pack_end(button_);

    button_.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::onButtonClicked));

    aboutw_ = 0;

    this->show_all_children();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::onButtonClicked()
{
    if(aboutw_ != 0)
        return;

    aboutw_ = new AboutWindow;
    aboutw_->signal_hide().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::aboutWinClose));
    aboutw_->show();
}

void MainWindow::aboutWinClose()
{
    aboutw_ = 0;
}
```

Added for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the new window to be modal, then simply create it, `show()` it, and return from your main window's method *without* entering a loop.

Comment: Hello there, Could you please give some example code?